# How to merge two dataframes with MultiIndex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multi-index

I have a frame looks like:

```
            2015-12-30  2015-12-31
300100  am    1             3
        pm    3             2
300200  am    5             1
        pm    4             5
300300  am    2             6
        pm    3             7
```

and the other frame looks like

```
            2016-1-1    2016-1-2    2016-1-3    2016-1-4
300100  am    1           3            5           1
        pm    3           2            4           5
300200  am    2           5            2           6
        pm    5           1            3           7
300300  am    1           6            3           2
        pm    3           7            2           3
300400  am    3           1            1           3
        pm    2           5            5           2
300500  am    1           6            6           1
        pm    5           7            7           5
```

Now I want to merge the two frames, and the frame after merge to be looked like this:

```
             2015-12-30 2015-12-31  2016-1-1    2016-1-2    2016-1-3    2016-1-4
  300100  am    1          3           1           3           5           1
          pm    3          2           3           2           4           5
  300200  am    5          1           2           5           2           6
          pm    4          5           5           1           3           7
  300300  am    2          6           1           6           3           2
          pm    3          7           3           7           2           3
  300400  am                           3           1           1           3
          pm                           2           5           5           2
  300500  am                           1           6           6           1
          pm                           5           7           7           5
```

I tried pd.merge(frame1,frame2,right_index=True,left_index=True), but what it returned was not the desired format. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What is `frame1.index` and `frame2.index` ? What is problem with output?

Comment: frame1.index is MultiIndex(levels=[[300100.0, 300200.0, 300300.0], ['am', 'pm']],
           labels=[[0, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

Comment: frame2.index is MultiIndex(levels=[[300100.0, 300200.0, 300300.0, 300400.0, 300500.0], ['am', 'pm']],
           labels=[[0, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, 4, -1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]). Part of the output looks like 2016-02-01 00:00:00_x  2016-02-02 00:00:00_x  \
300100.0 am                      1                      3   
300200.0 am                      5                      1   
300300.0 am                      2                      6

Comment: Thank you. But I think better is if you change your pictures to text (because is impossible copy your sample data) and add your problematic output to question text, because problematic formating in comments.

Comment: One idea - how does work `pd.concat([frame1, frame2], axis=1)` or `pd.concat([frame1, frame2], axis=1, join='inner')` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and I have replaced the pictures with text. I tried your codes but both of them returned "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index"

Comment: Thank you for pics. Problem with `concat` is with your sample (for me it works nice) or only with real data?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It actually works! Thanks. But I have one more question: after concat, the values for 300100, 300200 and 300300 on 2015-12-30 and 2015-12-31 are displayed as 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 instead of 1, 2, 3, but other values are fine. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.concat([frame1, frame2], axis=1))
           2015-12-30  2015-12-31  1.1.2016  2.1.2016  3.1.2016  4.1.2016
300100 am         1.0         3.0         1         3         5         1
       pm         3.0         2.0         3         2         4         5
300200 am         5.0         1.0         2         5         2         6
       pm         4.0         5.0         5         1         3         7
300300 am         2.0         6.0         1         6         3         2
       pm         3.0         7.0         3         7         2         3
300400 am         NaN         NaN         3         1         1         3
       pm         NaN         NaN         2         5         5         2
300500 am         NaN         NaN         1         6         6         1
       pm         NaN         NaN         5         7         7         5
```

Values in first and second column are converted to `float`, because `NaN` values convert `int` to `float` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

One possible solution is replace `NaN` by some `int` e.g. `0` and then convert to `int`:

```
print (pd.concat([frame1, frame2], axis=1)
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
           2015-12-30  2015-12-31  1.1.2016  2.1.2016  3.1.2016  4.1.2016
300100 am           1           3         1         3         5         1
       pm           3           2         3         2         4         5
300200 am           5           1         2         5         2         6
       pm           4           5         5         1         3         7
300300 am           2           6         1         6         3         2
       pm           3           7         3         7         2         3
300400 am           0           0         3         1         1         3
       pm           0           0         2         5         5         2
300500 am           0           0         1         6         6         1
       pm           0           0         5         7         7         5
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `join`

```
frame1.join(frame2, how='outer')
```

[image]